# Evaluate $\int_{\frac12}^2e^{\left|x-\frac1x\right|}\,dx$

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, exponential-function

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{\frac12}^2e^{\left|x-\frac1x\right|}\,dx$

$\left|x-\frac1x\right|=\left|\frac{x^2-1}x\right|=\begin{cases}x-\frac1x,&x\in[-1,0)\cup[1,\infty)\\-x+\frac1x,&x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,1)\end{cases}$

Thus, $\displaystyle\int_{\frac12}^2e^{\left|x-\frac1x\right|}dx=\displaystyle\int_{\frac12}^1e^{x-\frac1x}dx+\displaystyle\int_1^2e^{-x+\frac1x}dx$

If I put $x-\frac1x=t$, I get $(1+\frac1{x^2})dx=dt$. Don't know how to use it.

I tried $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)dx=\displaystyle\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$ but couldn't conclude with that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$I = \int_{\frac12}^2e^{|x-\frac1x|} \mathrm{d}x  $$
Put $u = \dfrac1x \implies \mathrm{d}x = - \dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2}$
$$I = \int_{\frac12}^2 e^{|u-\frac1u|} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2}$$
Add both the integrals
$$ \begin{align} 2I &\ = \int_{\frac12}^2  \left(1 + \frac{1}{u^2} \right)e^{|u-\frac1u|}\mathrm{d}u \\ &\ = \int_{\frac12}^1  \left(1 + \frac{1}{u^2} \right)e^{-(u-\frac1u)}\mathrm{d}u+\int_1^2  \left(1 + \frac{1}{u^2} \right)e^{u-\frac1u}\mathrm{d}u \end{align}$$
Now substitute $ u-\dfrac1u = t \implies \left(1 + \dfrac{1}{u^2} \right)\mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{d}t $

Comment: Exploiting $x\mapsto 1/x$ symmetry of both the interval $[1/2,2]$ and the integrand is surely the way. Not guaranteed to work always, but here it helps.